Installing make and gcc on a Windows machine
I am trying to add windows-latest as a target to this workflow:
name: Arena Tests

on: [workflow_dispatch, push, pull_request]

jobs:
  test_cross_platform:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Build
        run: make
      - name: Run tests
        run: make test

Currently, adding windows-latest in the list fails because make is unrecognized.
According to: runner-images, the package manager for windows-latest is Chocolatey Software, which has packages for MinGW-w64 13.2.0 and GNU make 4.4.1 that can be installed with:
choco install mingw
choco install make

My question is: After adding these to the YML file, would I need to play around with the PATH environment variable or do something else before I can simply run:
make
make test

on the Windows machine, similar to MacOS and Linux?
Note: The code is written in Standard C99, and does not depend on anything POSIX-specific, and should compile cleanly on Windows.

I'd recommend installing them from MSYS2 instead, and use msys2/setup-msys2@v2 action to get it into the PATH.

Personally I would recommend using MSYS2 for workflows, especially when building for multiple platforms.
Here is the workflow for a minimal project I created to illustrate how to build for Windows + MacOS + Linux:
https://github.com/brechtsanders/ci-test/blob/master/.github/workflows/ci-test.yml
